# Meaning of: Array1 : .word 0:20

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

What is the meaning of :

```
Array1 :    .word 0:20
```

Comment: I am not familiar with mips assembly. Does 0:20 indicate a bit field?

Comment: I myself could not get this statement....and therefore I posted this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array1 :` is a label (the space is optional).

For MIPS, a `:<n>` suffix to an expression in directives such as `.word`, `.byte` etc. is a repeat count.

So `Array1 : .word 0:20` creates a block of 20 words (i.e. 80 bytes) of 0, with the label `Array1` pointing to the start of it.

(Footnote: The GNU assembler, `gas`, tends to try to follow the "traditional" assembler syntax for each platform; a brief glance suggests that this syntax is not that common on other platforms - only MIPS and Alpha obviously support it.)

Comment: Would this equate to `Array1: .space 80` in MIPS64?